# Save protobuf directly as entity using JpaRepository

Tags: spring-boot, protocol-buffers

I have a protocol buffer message as input, which I want to save into my database directly using .save() method of JpaRepository. However, if I try to extend my repository to JpaRepository, it throws error as ProtoClass is not an Entity.

How can I save this protoClass directly ?

Comment: did you found a way?

Answer (score -4):

Check your ProtoClass define like this

```
@Entity
class ProtoClass{
 //......
}
```

I think you are missing @Entity.

Comment: The ProtoClass being talked about here is a generated class and the question itself is asked because you can't annotate the class with @Entity

Comment: @Vijay Pal Vishwakarma - can you please ping me your email for collaboration.